# Сложная фильтрация в JTable

Tags: java, swing, filter

Написал такую фильтрацию(точное совпадение числа):

```
        RowFilter<TableModel,  java.lang.Object> rowFilter = null;
        ArrayList<RowFilter<TableModel, java.lang.Object>> filters = new ArrayList<>();

        RowFilter<TableModel, java.lang.Object> filter1 = null;
        filter1 = RowFilter.regexFilter(
                p_Dy.getText().isEmpty() ? "" : "^" + p_Dy.getText()+"$"
                        , 3);

        filters.add(filter1);

        RowFilter<TableModel, java.lang.Object> filter2 = null;
        filter2 = RowFilter.regexFilter(
                p_dy.getText().isEmpty() ? "" : "^" + p_dy.getText()+"$"
                , 4);

        filters.add(filter2);

        rowFilter = RowFilter.andFilter(filters);

        tblPanel.setFilter(rowFilter);
```

Как оказалось, нужно было сделать фильтр что бы оставлял не больше 2 ближайших нижних значения в таблице и 2 ближайших верхних от того что было введено в поля p_Dy и p_dy.
В столбцах хранятся стринги.
Может кто ни будь сможет помочь, как это вообще должно выглядеть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ничего нормального в голову не пришло(
Придется пихать такого монстра:

```
/**Возвращает регулярное выражение*/
private String getRegExp(String text){
    String reg = "";
    if(!text.equals("")){

        int avg = Integer.parseInt(text);
        int begin = avg - 50;

        if(begin < 0) begin = 0;

        for(int i = begin; i <= (avg + 50); i++)
            reg += i + "|";

        reg = reg.substring(0, reg.length()-1);
        reg = "^(" + reg + ")$";
    }
    return reg;
}
```